# removing letter followed by three of four numbers in php

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove part of string in my php script. The strings will be similar to this one: 
Samsung I8730 Galaxy Express

I need to remove part "I8730", this will be used on other models like "i9500", "B2100", etc. etc.

Please assist with some preg_replace pattern or something that will fix this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A letter is `[A-Za-z]`. A number is `\d`.

```
/[A-Za-z]\d{3,4}/
```

Answer (score 0):

First explode the string using on " ".

And then use preg_match() for the following regex.

```
    ^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex and replace by nothing, this one matches if string has at least 1 char and 1 number:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

assume that after character there can be 2-5 intergers

```
$str = 'Samsung I8730 Galaxy Express';
echo preg_replace( '/([a-zA-Z][0-9]{2,5} )/','', $str);
```

This might helpful